# Method must have return type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I keep getting this error when I try to build my solution. I've tried `public string` and just `public` but can't get it to work. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
[WebMethod]
public static LoadCitiesByState(string state)
{
        DataTable dt = SharedDataAccess.GetCities(state);
        List<string> cities = new List<string>();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            cities.Add(row[0].ToString());
        }
        return cities;

   }
```

**EDIT**

Now I get the error: "Not all code paths return a value"

**EDIT II**

Sorry forgot to paste the try & catch I had in there. I removed them and it worked. If anyone wants to show how to get it to work with a try & catch, feel free though.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't change the code of your function, because for me that code doesn't throw that error

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to specify the type of the variable you're returning:

```
public static List<string> LoadCitiesByState(string state)
```

#### edit for try/catch:

You need to make sure that something gets returned regardless of whether there is an exception thrown or not. So declare the return variable beforehand, and return it *after* the try/catch block:

```
public static List<string> LoadCitiesByState(string state)
{
    List<string> cities = new List<string>();
    try {
        DataTable dt = SharedDataAccess.GetCities(state);
    } catch // specify exceptions here
    {
        //exception handling
    }
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        cities.Add(row[0].ToString());
    }
    return cities;
}
```

In general it's always a good idea to minimize the number of lines you have inside the try block.

Comment: This helped but encountered another issue with that. Edit above.

Comment: Is that the entirety of the function? "Not all code paths return a value" means there's a branch somewhere which doesn't have a `return` statement at the end of it, but I'm not seeing one in what you've pasted above.

Comment: Yes, that's the whole function. I'm passing it a state via AJAX

Comment: @TCC - I added code to show how to do it with a try/catch, see if that works for you.

Comment: @tzaman "In general it's always a good idea to minimize the number of lines you have inside the try block."  Yes, but your code won't compile, as the `DataTable dt` is scoped only inside the `try` block.  The `foreach` needs to go inside the `try` block too.  And I wouldn't have a try block here; if you can't connect to the database it's a serious, probably fatal problem that needs to bubble-up to where it can be handled sensibly.

Answer (score 6):

You are returning cities with is a `List<string>` so that should be your return type.

`public static List<string> LoadCitiesByState(string state)`

Answer (score 4):

the problem with your method it's that you need to define which type of data are you going to return

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> LoadCitiesByState(string state)
{
    DataTable dt = SharedDataAccess.GetCities(state);
    List<string> cities = new List<string>();

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        cities.Add(row[0].ToString());
    }
    return cities;

}
```

And that's all

**UPDATE**

If you want to add the try and catch you could do it like this

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> LoadCitiesByState(string state)
{

    List<string> cities = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = SharedDataAccess.GetCities(state);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            cities.Add(row[0].ToString());
        }
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
          //logs your exception 
     }

    return cities;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify return type, try this

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> LoadCitiesByState(string state)
{
        DataTable dt = SharedDataAccess.GetCities(state);
        List<string> cities = new List<string>();

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            cities.Add(row[0].ToString());
        }
        return cities;

}
```